# Creating Org Structure from An Employee Class

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLastname { get; set; }
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

And the following objects:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.Department = "C Level";
emp1.EmployeeID = 1;
emp1.EmployeeLastname = "Smith";
emp1.EmployeeName = "Joe";

Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.Department = "B Level";
emp2.EmployeeID = 2;
emp2.EmployeeLastname = "Smith";
emp2.EmployeeName = "John";
emp2.ManagerID = 1;

Employee emp3 = new Employee();
emp3.Department = "A Level";
emp3.EmployeeID = 3;
emp3.EmployeeLastname = "Mallari";
emp3.EmployeeName = "Lem";
emp3.ManagerID = 2;
```

I need to create a method which needs an employee id and returns a single Employee object which contains the org structure. So for example if I search for employee 1 it returns me the following:

```
Employee
  EmployeeID: 1
  EmployeeName: Joe
  EmployeeLastName: Smith
  Department: C Level
  ManagerID: null
  Manager: null
```

But for example if I search for Employee ID 3 it will return me the following:

```
Employee
  EmployeeID: 3
  EmployeeName: Lem
  EmployeeName: Mallari
  Department: A Level
  ManagerID: 2
  Manager:
    EmployeeID: 2
    EmployeeName: John
    EmployeeLastname: Smith
    Department: B Level
    ManagerID: 1
    Manager: 
      EmployeeID: 1
      EmployeeName: Joe
      EmployeeLasname: Smith
      Department: C Level
      ManagerID: null
      Manager: null
```

I was able to create a method already which gets the details of the manager given an ID and link that manager to the employee originally searched. I just can't think of a way to continuously search for a manager and updating the property of an object an be able to create the structure I need.

Comment: The composite design pattern may be a good starting point for this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is already in C#.

```
var employee3 = emps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == 3);
```

Your `employee3` contains already all the information of the managers.

```
var manager = employee3?.Manager?.Manager;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use recursion to reconstruct the object graph. Downside is that you would need all employees in memory.

```
public class EmployeeSearcher
{
    private IEnumerable<Employee> _employees;

    public EmployeeSearcher(IEnumerable<Employee> employees) => _employees = employees;

    public Employee Search(int id)
    {
        var employee = _employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == id);

        if (employee == null) throw new Exception($"Employee not found: {id}");
        FindManagerRecursive(employee);

        return employee;
    }
    private void FindManagerRecursive(Employee employee)
    {
        if (!employee.ManagerID.HasValue) return;
        var manager = _employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == employee.ManagerID.Value);

        if (manager == null) throw new Exception("Manager not found: {employee.ManagerID}");
        employee.Manager = manager;
        FindManagerRecursive(manager);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var searcher = new EmployeeSearcher(new List<Employee> { emp1, emp2, emp3});
var result = searcher.Search(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below at any point you will know who all are the employees and who is the manager and then with your employee object you can traverse upwards or downwards.

```
class Program
    {
       static List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Employee emp1 = new Employee();
            emp1.Department = "C Level";
            emp1.EmployeeID = 1;
            emp1.EmployeeLastname = "Smith";
            emp1.EmployeeName = "Joe";
            lstEmployee.Add(emp1);

            Employee emp2 = new Employee();
            emp2.Department = "B Level";
            emp2.EmployeeID = 2;
            emp2.EmployeeLastname = "Smith";
            emp2.EmployeeName = "John";
            emp2.ManagerID = 1;
            lstEmployee.Add(emp2);

            Employee emp3 = new Employee();
            emp3.Department = "A Level";
            emp3.EmployeeID = 3;
            emp3.EmployeeLastname = "Mallari";
            emp3.EmployeeName = "Lem";
            emp3.ManagerID = 2;
            lstEmployee.Add(emp3);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
            public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
            public string EmployeeLastname { get; set; }
            public int ManagerID { get; set; }
            public Employee Manager
            {
                get
                {
                    return (from a in lstEmployee where a.EmployeeID == ManagerID select a).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            public List<Employee> Reportees
            {
                get
                {
                    return (from a in lstEmployee where a.ManagerID == EmployeeID select a).ToList();
                }
            }
            public string Department { get; set; }
        }
    }
```